# Pure value from JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I sit and try with some Python programming where I need to get data out of a JSON object. This can be done with the get_data method, but then I also get the designation and I only want the value, how do I do it?

The code look like this

```html
import json
from omdbapi.movie_search import GetMovie

movie = GetMovie(title='Interstellar', api_key='xxxxxx', plot='full')

Title = movie.get_data('Title')
Year = movie.get_data('Year')
print(Title)
print(Year)
```

And I get this result

```html
======== RESTART: C:\Users\TELESHOP\Desktop\Johnny\Python\webtest1.py ========
{'Title': 'Interstellar'}
{'Year': '2014'}
>>>
```

But only want this

```html
======== RESTART: C:\Users\TELESHOP\Desktop\Johnny\Python\webtest1.py ========
Interstellar
2014
>>>
```

Comment: it seems you get dictionary in variable `Title` so you can do `Title['Title']`. You can check if it is really dictionary `print( type(Title) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the bottom part:

```
...
Title = movie.get_data('Title')['Title']
Year = movie.get_data('Year')['Year']
print(Title)
print(Year)
```

It will output:

```
Interstellar
2014
```

Comment: Many thanks, i am brand new to both Python and this forum, so it is delicious with a place like here to ask in